# Загрузка файла по URI (C#)

Tags: c#

Интересует возможность использования браузера для скачивания файла по указанию локального адреса. Т.е. чтобы не указывать путь для его сохранения, а для этого использовались настройки браузера. Именно поэтому копирование файла не подходит.

Есть метод `DownloadFile(String, String)` класса `WebClient`, который якобы позволяет это сделать. Но как правильно указать оба параметра - не могу разобраться.

Так вот. Как правильно объявить параметры в виде:
- первый: `new Uri("c:\\myfile.txt")` (если это возможно).
- второй: "c:\myfile.txt"?

Или возможен другой путь для для решения моего вопроса?

Comment: С помощью WebClient действительно можно "скопировать" локальный файл указав путь к файлу и указав имя для сохранения(файл будет сохранен рядом с экзешником). Вот только есть вопрос, а причем тут браузер? Вы собрались использовать вебклиент в браузере?

Comment: Так мне же копировать не надо с помощью браузера! Мне нужно имея  URI в виде локальной записи "c:\myfile.txt" скачать в папку загрузок вне зависимости с какого браузера я скачиваю этот файл. Проблема в том, как правильно задать аргументы этого метода.

Comment: @vitaliklibra вы хотите записывать файлы в кеш браузера? а для чего такое надо?

Comment: Разве я упомянул, что дело касается кеша?) Вы когда скачиваете файл, к примеру с Яндекс.Диска, по прямой ссылке, вы выбираете куда скачивать? Или браузер по умолчанию предлагает путь для сохранения? Думаю, второе. Вам остается только нажать кнопку "Сохранить". Так вот мне это и нужно.

Comment: @vitaliklibra _"браузер по умолчанию предлагает путь для сохранения"_ -- это путь скорее всего берется из реестра.

Comment: @Stack Пусть даже так. А логика метода DownloadFile(String, String) как работает? https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms144194(v=vs.110).aspx - тут нету никаких реестров. Все должно быть проще...

Comment: @vitaliklibra _"А логика метода DownloadFile(String, String) как работает?"_ -- первый параметр - это url, по этому адресу должен работать веб-сервер. посмотрите в моем ответе: update.

Comment: Ну, не URL, а URI) Да и зачем мне веб-сервер, если я это использую в пределах локальной машины?

Answer (score 1):

> использования браузера для скачивания файла по указанию локального адреса.

Если надо открыть файл в WebBrowser'е, то можно сделать так:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

var f = new Form();
var b = new WebBrowser() { Parent = f, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
b.Navigate(@"C:\Temp\test.txt");   
f.ShowDialog();
```

---

UPDATE:

WebClient.DownloadFile(url, path) предназначен для скачивания файлов с веб-серверов. Если у вас на компьютере нет веб-сервера или он отключен или не настроен для работы с указанным url, то будет ошибка.

---

Браузер получает путь к Downloads, читая значение из реестра.

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER
 \Software
  \Microsoft
   \Windows
    \CurrentVersion
     \Explorer
      \User Shell Folders
       {374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B} = %USERPROFILE%\Downloads`

Comment: Эта информация мне может пригодиться, но вообще - это путь к стандартной папке с загрузками, но никак не браузера. У каждого обозревателя это значение свое и это совсем не универсальный способ.

Comment: @vitaliklibra браузер Edge читает значение из реестра. можете посмотреть сами. [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477804)

Answer (score 1):

Я не понял причём тут браузер, но с помощью `WebClient` можно сделать так:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile(@"C:\source.txt", @"C:\destionation.txt");
}
```

Первый параметр откуда загружаем, второй куда.

Но если Вам надо работать только с локальными файлами, то лучше воспользоваться другим классом:

```
File.Copy(@"C:\source.txt", @"C:\destionation.txt");
```

**UPD:**

Загрузка с использованием пути по умолчанию взятым для Internet Explorer (из этого ответа https://stackoverflow.com/a/24673279/4278250):

```
String path = String.Empty;

RegistryKey rKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main");
if (rKey != null)
    path = (String)rKey.GetValue("Default Download Directory");

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
    path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + "\\downloads";

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile(@"C:\source.txt", Path.Combine(path, "some file name.txt"));
}
```

Comment: У меня нет пути, куда сохранять. Путь должен использоваться тот, который по умолчанию указан в браузере.

Comment: @vitaliklibra, может это `%userprofile%\downloads`?

Comment: @vitaliklibra, если это не тот путь, то Вам поможет вот этот ответ http://stackoverflow.com/a/24673279/4278250

Comment: @vitaliklibra, обновил ответ

Answer (score 1):

По сути, вам нужно узнать, по какому пути браузер будет скачивать файл.

Для Internet Explorer'а это делается через P/Invoke + Shell32 (украдено из [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21953690/276994)):

```
[DllImport("Shell32.dll")]
private static extern int SHGetKnownFolderPath(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]Guid rfid, uint dwFlags, IntPtr hToken,
    out IntPtr ppszPath);

var downloadFolderGuid = new Guid("{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}");
IntPtr pathPtr;
int result = SHGetKnownFolderPath(
        downloadFolderGuid, (uint)0x00004000, new IntPtr(0), out pathPtr);
if (result >= 0)
    return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pathPtr);

throw new ExternalException("Unable to retrieve the known folder path. It may not "
            + "be available on this system.", result);
```

(полный код для других случаев и значение констант смотрите в ответе по ссылке).

Для других браузеров вам понадобятся специфические для этих браузеров методы.

---

Имея путь, вам нужно просто загрузить файл по нужному пути, используя `webClient.DownloadFile`:

```
using (var c = new WebClient())
    c.DownloadFile("http://www.google.com/", Path.Combine(directory, "index.html"));
```

Или скопировать туда, если у вас всё в пределах одного хоста:

```
File.Copy(@"C:\test.html", Path.Combine(directory, "test.html"));
```

Comment: а для браузера Microsoft Edge будет работать?

Comment: Нужно не "http://...", а локальный адрес.

Comment: @Stack: Не могу сказать (у меня нету 10-ки), но думаю, что вполне. Они ж не deprecate'нут Shell32?

Comment: @vitaliklibra: Подождите, как это не http? Вы ведь хотите загружать файл из **интернета**, правильно?

Comment: @VladD _"(у меня нету 10-ки), но думаю, что вполне"_ -- понятно. Edge отличается от IE.

Comment: @VladD Вы первый пост читали внимательно?)) "для скачивания файла по указанию локального адреса".

Comment: @vitaliklibra: Если вам нужно скопировать файл в пределах одного компьютера, то зачем вам WebClient? Просто скопируйте файл. Вы ж для копирования одной переменной в другую WebClient не используете, а копируете прямо, верно?

Comment: @Stack: Отличается-то конечно, но какой смысл им ломать существующее API? Есть функция `SHGetKnownFolderPath`, какой смысл ей неправильно работать с Edge? Microsoft же не враги сами себе. Но это, конечно, спекуляция, если есть что-то в документации, я бы почитал.

Comment: @VladD Ну, не в пределах одного компьютера, а там задействована локальная сеть, но для упрощения можно сказать, что в пределах одного компьютера. Просто скачивание мне нужно организовать не просто копированием, а именно скачиванием, чтобы файл помещался в общую папку для загрузок, куда сохраняются файлы, скачанные из интернета.

Comment: @vitaliklibra: Если это в пределах хоста, то это копирование, а не загрузка. Не стреляйте из пушки по воробьям! Единственное, что вам нужно — это целевой каталог.

Comment: @VladD _"какой смысл им ломать существующее API"_ -- избавляются от зависимости от WinAPI -- из-за UWP, которые могут работать на разных платформах. видели рекламу Lumia - смартфон работает как ПК?

Comment: @VladD Копирование, верно. Но конечного пути у меня нет. Он прописан в браузере. У хрома свой, у оперы свой в IE свой. Мне нужно чтобы их настройки использовались автоматически. Вы же не выбираете каждый раз при скачивании файла, куда Вам его сохранять? Вам браузер УЖЕ предлагает какой-то вариант, верно? Вот этот вариант мне и нужен.

Comment: @Stack: Ну, они WinAPI кладут сверху (как враппер на новое API), так что почему бы не сделать так, чтобы `SHGetKnownFolderPath` работало _тоже_ правильно? Это практически бесплатно.

Comment: @vitaliklibra: А вы ответ читали? Большая часть ответа именно про это.

Comment: @vitaliklibra _"Вам браузер УЖЕ предлагает какой-то вариант, верно?"_ -- проверил в Edge, предлагает Downloads. добавил в ответ.