# Как в Windows отследить активность программы?

Tags: windows

Как в Windows отследить активность программы?
Возможно ли узнать какие файлы и ветки системного реестра программа читает или меняет?

Answer (score 14):

Отслеживать активность приложений Windows в режиме реального времени можно с помощью Process Monitor, который  отображает активность файловой системы, реестра, а также процессов и потоков.
Process Monitor можно скачать с [Microsoft Technet - Sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx).