# Как ускорить чтение директорий файловой системы?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, файловая-система

Надо сканировать огромное количество файлов и папок. Обычно для этого используется метод `Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries`. 
Возможно ли как-то ускорить процесс чтения файловой системы?

Answer (score 11):

Можно ускорить почти в два раза, если использовать WinAPI.

```
// Microsoft (R) Roslyn C# Compiler version 1.1.0.51204
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")] static extern int GetLastError();
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")] static extern bool FindClose(IntPtr handle);
class SafeHandle : Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid {
    private SafeHandle() : base(true) { }
    protected override bool ReleaseHandle() { return FindClose(this.handle); }
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
struct DATA {       // WIN32_FIND_DATA
    public FileAttributes FileAttributes;
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME CreationTime;
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME LastAccessTime;
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME LastWriteTime;
    public uint FileSizeHigh;
    public uint FileSizeLow;
    public uint Reserved0;
    public uint Reserved1;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
    public string FileName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 14)]
    public string AlternateFileName;
}
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern SafeHandle FindFirstFileEx(string name, int i, 
                                         out DATA data, int so, IntPtr sf, int f);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern bool FindNextFile(SafeHandle h, out DATA data);
```

---

```
IEnumerable<DATA> ReadPath(string path) {  // например: "c:\" | "c:\*.png" | "c:\*"
    DATA d;
    var p = String.Concat(@"\\?\", path.TrimEnd('\\', ' '));
    using (var h = FindFirstFileEx(p, 1, out d, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 2)) {
        if (h.IsInvalid) throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(GetLastError());
        yield return d;
        while (FindNextFile(h, out d)) if (d.FileName != "..") yield return d;
        var e = GetLastError();   // e = 18 -- дошли до конца
        if (e != 18) throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(e);
    }
}
```

---

Получить файлы и папки в `c:\`:

```
foreach (var d in ReadPath(@"c:\*")) 
   Console.WriteLine("name=" + d.FileName);
```

---

Получить файлы в `c:\temp\` и подпапках:

```
class File { public string Path; public string Name; }
IEnumerable<File> Scan(string path) {
    foreach (var d in ReadPath(path + "*").Skip(1)) {
        // сканируем только подпапки, а junction пропускаем
        if ((d.FileAttributes & FileAttributes.Directory) != 0
            && (d.FileAttributes & FileAttributes.ReparsePoint) == 0)
            foreach (var f in Scan(path + d.FileName + "\\")) 
               yield return f;
        else
            yield return new File { Path = path, Name = d.FileName };
    }
}

long ToLong(uint high, uint low) { return (long)(((UInt64)high << 0x20) | (UInt64)low); }

foreach (var f in Scan(@"c:\temp\")) 
   Console.WriteLine(
      f.Path + "\t\t\t" + f.Name + " size=" + ToLong(d.FileSizeHigh, d.FileSizeLow));
```

Comment: `[DllImport("kernel32.dll")] static extern int GetLastError();` - вместо этого [надо](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17918729/4928642) использовать [Marshal.GetLastWin32Error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error.aspx).

Comment: _"А за счёт чего происходит ускорение?"_ -- тут прямые вызовы WinAPI. а в `Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries` очень много всего. посмотрите [исходник](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directory.cs,937)

Comment: @Qwertiy _"надо использовать Marshal.GetLastWin32Error"_ -- выдает неправильный код если Tasks.Task и много подзадач (т.е. TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent). примера под рукой нет, и возможно это был какой-то побочный эффект. как-нибудь проверю и напишу.

Comment: А по ссылке утверждается, что наоборот winapi-вариант может дать неправильный код, если там сборщик мусора запустится.

Comment: @Qwertiy _"winapi-вариант может дать неправильный код,"_ -- от версии CLR зависит, как там сказано: _"If you compile this with .NET2, it will produce "2 / 0"; if you switch to .NET 4, it will output "2 / 2""_. т.е. надо проверять.

Comment: @VladD _"вы вроде бы не закрываете хендл, а надеетесь на сборщик мусора."_ -- где не закрываю? вы смотрели на SafeHandle и на using?

Comment: @Stack: А, точно, закрываете. Окей, вы не обрабатываете ошибки кроме no more files и file not found. (http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/__error.cs,142.) Ну и код в BCL идёт тоже через те же нативные функции, но делает больше — вы и вправду считаете, что всё, что они там делают, лишнее, и это можно безболезненно выкинуть?

Comment: @VladD _"точно, закрываете. Окей, вы не обрабатываете ошибки"_ -- напомнили "а на цепочку закрыл?)". это пример-основа. кому надо тот может дописать то, что требуется. _"вы и вправду считаете, что всё, что они там делают, лишнее"_ -- про все сказать не могу. не смотрел. главное что код работает быстрее чем .Enumerate* и делает то, что мне надо. если найдете баг, напишите.

Comment: @VladD _"Это для FindNext, а не для FindFirst"_ -- а для FindFrst.. тоже есть, см. if (h.IsInvalid) throw ...

Comment: @VladD, валидный хендл одновременно с ошибкой? Это возможно?

Comment: @VladD _"валидный хендл одновременно с ошибкой?"_ -- если при вызове FindFirstFileEx возникнет ошибка, то h.IsInvalid = true. _"Я не хочу копать ошибки, это было бы не очень этично с моей стороны."_ -- я не обижусь если найдете. мне самому инетересно в каких ситуациях этот код сломается.

Comment: @Stack: Если каталог пустой (или файлов по маске не найдено?), то [`FindFirstFileEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) по идее возвращает `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, у вас это, кажется, приведёт к исключению.

Comment: @VladD _"Если каталог пустой (или файлов по маске не найдено?) ... у вас это, кажется, приведёт к исключению"_ -- да. потому что если garbage in, то fail-fast.

Comment: @VladD, кстати, у этого кода ещё полезный момент есть - он должен уметь обрабатывать пути длиннее 256 символов за счёт ``\\?\``.

Comment: @Stack: Э, не, пустой каталог не должен быть ошибкой. Чем количество файлов 0 хуже, чем 5?

Comment: @VladD _"пустой каталог не должен быть ошибкой"_ -- если нужны данные по папке, то не надо ставить суффикс `\*` и не будет ошибки. а если ставите `\*` то значит намеревались получить содержимое, но его нет - значит fail fast.

Comment: По поводу обработки длинных имён — я читал у разработчиков BCL, почему они не обрабатывают длинные имена. Дело в том, что это по сути бесполезно — вы ведь передадите имя файла на дальнейшую обработку другим системным функциям, а у них снова ограничение в 260 символов. Это как-бы неправильно, ограничение должно быть общесистемным, и исправляться на общесистемном уровне, а не костылём.

Comment: Я здесь согласен с @Qwertiy — если я, например, хочу удалить или там забекапить все файлы в 50 заранее заданных каталогах, то обработать 0 файлов в каком-то из каталогов нормально.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Это потому, что он должен использоваться во всех случаях, даже когда нужна экстремальная скорость, а у нас тут как бы конкретный, в котором время обработки подавляет всё остальное. То есть с технической стороны вы, скорее всего, правы, но мне это кажется слишком мелкой монетой, чтобы за ней нагибаться.

Comment: @VladD _"Должна быть пустая коллекция, а не ошибка"_ -- нет ошбки. видно, код не запускали. так вот в любой папке есть записи `.` и `..`. и если `..` отфильтровывается, то `.` возвращается и для пустой папки при запросе с суффиксом `\*`

Comment: Хм. А вот это уже серьёзнее. В худшем случае будет затёртая память со всеми своими прелестями.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Опередили :)

Comment: @Qwertiy _"с 260 там всё равно что-то не то будет, наверное:"_ -- эти 260 это только на имя файла, без пути. путь передается только на входе в FindFirstFileEx, а на выходе только имена

Comment: @Qwertiy _"если маской будет не *, а какой-нибудь *.txt"_ -- в коде в комменте перечислены примеры. один из них как-раз "*.png"

Comment: @VladD _"В худшем случае будет затёртая память со всеми своими прелестями"_ -- данные передаются из WinAPI наружу в DATA. так что все ок. а если нет, то значит это баг в WinAPI. но пока никто жаловался.

Comment: @Qwertiy _"а в 2 раза на чём-то ведь замерялось"_ -- с помощью Stopwatch смотрел сколько ElapsedMilliseconds  при сканировании папки с 10 тыс. файлов в EnumerateFileSystemEntries и сколько в ReadPath. запускал несколько раз.

Comment: @VladD _"проблема будет только если имя файла длиннее 260 символов"_ -- такого имени (только имени; без пути) не будет, т.к. его просто не получится создать. а вот длина всего пути до файла может быть равна 32767

Comment: _в коде в комменте перечислены примеры. один из них как-раз "*.png"_ - имелось в виду, что будет в случае пустой папки при такой маске? ведь `.` и `..` ей уже не соответствуют.

Comment: @Qwertiy _"а если на структуре замерить?"_ -- я что-то пропустил наверное. какой структуре? DATA это и так struct

Comment: `class File { public string Path; public string Name; }` - вот тут вместо class сделать struct.

Comment: @VladD _"А примонтированный сетевой диск?"_ -- если FindFirstFileEx может с ним работать, то все ок.

Comment: @Stack: Может, конечно. Вопрос в том, что там может быть файловая система с именами длиннее чем 260 символов. И `FindFirstFileEx` придётся вернуть какую-нибудь ошибку.

Comment: @Qwertiy _" вместо class сделать struct."_ -- попробую. но получится что в Scan будет создаваться структура, и yield return наружу. при этом будет копирование структуры, а не передача ссылки, не так ли?

Comment: Да, так. Но в структуре только две ссылки, т. е. копируемый размер увеличивается незначительно, а необходимость выделения памяти и сборки мусора отпадает.

Comment: @VladD _"может быть файловая система с именами длиннее чем 260 символов. И FindFirstFileEx придётся вернуть какую-нибудь ошибку"_ -- на входе ReadPath может быть строка.length = 32767; вы видели такой путь?

Comment: Кстати, я тут подумал насчёт ускорения в 2 раза - ты не собираешь конкатенацию строк чтобы получить полный путь, в отличие от стандартной функции - на этом можно сэкономить что-то. Потому что я не думаю, что прямое обращение к api как-то экономит на взаимодействии с файловой системой - скорее окружающий код.

Comment: @VladD _"длинные пути, что имя файла больше 260 символов"_ -- да, полный путь к файлу (т.е. весь путь и имя) чтобы был под 30 тыс. символов в длину.

Comment: @Qwertiy _" не собираешь конкатенацию строк чтобы получить полный путь"_ -- и не вызываю Path.GetFullPath, который вызывает ужасный [NormalizePath(path, true)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,363)

Comment: @Qwertiy _"вместо class сделать struct."_ -- проверил. для 9509 файлов. ElapsedMilliseconds, для `struct File` 34;30;28;27;28;39;27;28;27;27; для 
`class File` 30;27;26;27;28;29;28;32;29;27;

Comment: @Stack: Таких длинных нет. Но имя файла (не полный путь, а именно имя) длиннее 260 символов — да.

Comment: Как-то маловато. Я думал, ты там на несколько минут поиск запустил. А при 10К файлов даже не факт, что сборщик мусора хоть раз сработал.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34277/discussion-on-answer-by-stack------).

Comment: Судя по всему, вы проверяли результат на разогретом дисковом кэше - т.е. несколько раз читали одну и ту же папку, и брали среднее значение. В таких условиях у меня результат на 18к файлов - 500ms -> 300ms, т.е. почти в два раза. Это хороший результат, но стоит учитывать что при этом не происходит реального обращения к диску. В реальных условиях дисковых кэш скорее всего будет холодным, и я намерял в этом случае разницу 3700ms -> 3500ms. Можете привести конретные результаты измерений, указав тип диска (hdd/sdd) и состояние кэша перед измерениями?

Comment: @PashaPash _"состояние кэша перед измерениями"_ -- как определить состояние кэша? диск hdd. 99% времени 'спит'

Comment: @Stack Я использовал [утилиту RamMAP + сброс Standby Lists](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9649439/1988244). Она позволяет посмотреть конкретные закэшированные файлы, но вроде бы не позволяет закэшированные папки (т.е. то, что файлами не является) После сброса - при полностью пустом кэше, ваш код у меня отрабатывает за 10s (при 300-400ms на разогретом), и во время работы слышно как диск старается. На SSD на холодном кэше - около 900ms. На горячем - 400ms (почему-то чуть медленее, чем на HDD, скорее всего просто из-за системности диска)

Comment: @Stack т.е. код действительно применим, но основной профит он принесет в определенных условиях - например, для частого чтения одной и той же структуры папок в поисках изменений (ведь он нахяляву еще и даты файлов выдает).

Answer (score 2):

Нужно индексировать FS в базу данных и работать потом с базой.

Comment: _"индексировать FS в базу данных"_ -- как это сделать?

Comment: По хорошему драйвер на файловую систему навесить, по плохому тупо периодически обходить ее.

Comment: _"По хорошему драйвер на файловую систему навесить"_ -- это как-то сложно. и не всегда возможно.  _"периодически обходить ее"_ -- чтобы обходить ее быстро надо использовать WinAPI.

Comment: Смысл был в том чтобы один раз обойти FS и через драйвер ловить все изменения FS. Никакое WinAPI такой уровень поддержки актуальности индекса и быстроты обеспечить не может.

Comment: Т. е. если ты будешь делать программу, которой надо искать что-то на диске, ты к ней в комплект дашь драйвер, который будет следить за всеми действиями в файловой системе? Ну круто.

Comment: Если задача состоит в том что нужно искать очень и очень быстро, а не по полчаса - то да.

Comment: @cpp_user _"через драйвер ловить все изменения FS."_ -- а как это сделать? [Process Monitor](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/477805/196972) отлавливает все обращения к диску, но как это делается найти не смог.

Comment: Ищи по "File System Filter Driver - called on every file system I/O operation (create, read, write, rename, remove, ...)"

Comment: Кстати, а что будет с обновлением данных, если изменения будут внесены из другой ОС, например?

Comment: Это уже административная проблема, если у вас можно внести изменения другой осью(что мешает поставить драйвер и на эту ось?) или просто молотком по железу.