# Как ускорить процесс перебора файлов

Tags: c#

```
try
{
List<string> Picture = new List<string>();
            List<string> PaThS = new List<string>();
            string[] SVF =  {
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),  
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
                            };
            foreach (var paths in SVF)
                PaThS.AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories(paths));

            foreach (var e in PaThS)
                    Picture.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(e, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
}
catch{}
}
```

Здесь перебирает слишком долго,  пишу на *3.5 фрейморке*, на **4** хорошо идёт 
`EnumerateDirectories` и `EnumerateFiles`, А мне нужно на *3.5 фреймворке*. `GetFiles` слишком долго перебирает всё, Как можно ускорить процесс?
P.S: Вообще желательно без Linq))

Comment: Чистый WinAPI наверняка будет быстрее

Comment: Есть ссылка на него?

Comment: Ага, https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx например

Comment: Может вам убрать цикл и обьеденить `PaThS.AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories(GetFolderPath()+';'+GetFolderPath())` в один запрос?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/482449/178988

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, что нельзя значительно ускорить перебор файлов.

Если файлы находятся на одном диске и сделать многопоточность, то упретесь в производительность ЖД.

Если бы вы использовали EnumerateDirectories и EnumerateFiles, то в вашем бы случае это бы не дало особого результата, так как судя по коду вам нужен итог и между составлением списка вы ничего не обрабатываете. Т.е в любом случае вы бы ждали.

Можно заменить `List<String>`, на StringCollection, этот тип быстрее работает со строками.

Можно воспользоваться WinApi, как написали в комментариях, НО чудес не бывает и не стоит ждать огроменной прибавки к скорости.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/482449/178988

Comment: Коллекции из пространства имён System.Collections.Specialized были актуальны во времена первого фреймворка. После появления дженериков про них можно забыть.

Comment: @Qwertiy, что-то не верится в это. Ведь классы .NET -это теже обертки над WINAPI.

Comment: Вполне верится. 1. .NET объединяет путь с именем, а winapi - нет. Это пачка лишних конкатенаций, скорость которых зависит от длинны пути. 2. .NET возвращает массив, а winapi - поштучно файлы, значит есть дополнительные расходы на формирование массива (и изменение его длины).

Answer (score 1):

> Как можно ускорить процесс?

Про ускорение перебора файлов есть в [другом вопросе](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/482449/178988).

> на 4 хорошо идёт `EnumerateDirectories` и `EnumerateFiles`

Разница между Enumerate* и Get* в том, что первые возвращают файлы поштучно, а вторые собирают в массив. Из того, что enumerate тебя устраивали, могу сделать вывод, что на самом деле тебе нужно не ускорение, а просто чтобы UI не зависал на время поиска. В таком случае правильным решением будет вынести поиск файлов в отдельный поток.

Comment: @ArteS, а что там с linq?